# awk sum addition math on fields & colums $ - strange results

Tags: awk, calculated-columns

Please run this script. I wonder why I can not assing $1, $2 and $3 in BEGIN in order to calculate and print them:

```
    BEGIN {
        OFS=FS=";" ;
        #  @include getopt.awk
    geb = 4;
    dis = 3;
    $1 = 10;
    $2 = 0.19;
    $3 = 20;
    summe = geb+dis+$1;
    colsum = $1+$2+$3
}
{
    print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS "Fee" " "summe FS $1+$3 FS 3+4+$1 FS colsum}
```

For example I hoped that

```
print $1+$3
```

gives me 30 ?!
Can't I assign new values to fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BEGIN` block happens before awk begins processing the file, so it doesn't make sense to assign to the individual fields, as they will be overwritten once the first record is read.

If you wish to perform calculations on the records that awk reads, this should be done in a normal block, like the one you are using to `print`.

Comment: That works now. Thanks. One question arose now: When I rearange fields like original order $1, $2, $3 to $2,$1,$3 and a few lines later I use $1, am I then 'grabbing' the original field 1 or the new moved one ?

Comment: @prestalearner for every record that is read, `$1` is set to the first field. It doesn't matter what you did previously.

Comment: I had also to substitute all , in .

Comment: That was a time consumer to find that issue: gsub(/\,/,".");
negsum = ($10+$11)*-1; works now

Comment: If it is allowed to crossreference here I would like to get your focus on my main problem with awking my data sheet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977022/awk-two-regex-conditions-structure-convoluted-complex-transactions-list-csv?noredirect=1#comment73053005_42977022

Comment: @prestalearner I think the `,` vs `.` thing you're talking about is due to your locale setting so fixing that might work out better for you than manipulating your data in awk. Google locales.

Answer (score 0):

`BEGIN` blcoks are executed before any input is read (unless use `getline`), so consequently none of the variables that refer to input, like `NR`,`FNR`,`NF`, fields like `$0, $1, $2 ...$10` will be defined in any of the `BEGIN` blocks.

In fact `BEGIN` block is for actions to execute before you read the first line

**(unless use `getline`) - Not Recommended**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ seq 1 5 >test
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test 
1
2
3
4
5

# Default action by awk
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk 'BEGIN{print $1}' test

# if you use getline
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk 'BEGIN{getline;print $1}' test
1
```