# awk - when processing more than 1 file the condittion /pattern{...} stops working

Tags: awk

After days I got my awk actions working. I look for string "Transaktionen" and then the follwing lines shall be printed.  But only if I process one of my input files. If I process more than one, the script stops working. The output is far from what processing one file only outputs (it is convoluted again). Actually this part seems to break since lines appear from input in the output that are not conditioned or constraint by this:

```
/^Transaktionen/,/^$/ {print}
```

I open the input files like this (Windows):

```
gawk -f 1.awk pay*.csv > neu1.csv
```

So, I have a bunch of pay*.csv files. In a test I copied pay1.csv to pay2.csv and run the given line (above) neu1.txt is garbage. If I run the given line (above) seperately over pay1.csv and then oder pay2.csv all is fine.

Either my script does not allow this workflow, or my way of opening files is wrong or the way I try to output. May be outputting each pay*.csv > neu*.csv could help?

Is this enough information for you experts to reckon the reason why the script does not respect he conditon anymore? (I am asking since my original input and script might be confusing).

---

I post here my actual script I use. My input files (pay*.csv) always have in $1="Transaktionen" and then follow the records I am interested in. I do not understand why this IF Condition  /^Transaktionen/,/^$/ {all my stuff} breaks when processing several files. A dirty solution could be to to process with this awk script all input files (pay*.csv) and to 'output' each to its own output? I tried this but failed due to not finding the command for it. I failed to add sth like this: FNR == 1 { out = "new/"FILENAME } ; { print > out }' *.txt

```
    /^Transaktionen/,/^$/ {
/./;
NF > 0; 
gsub(/\-/,".");
if ((x=index($2," ")) > 0) {
    DDMMYY = substr($2,1,x-1);
    #minhours = substr($2,x+1,lenght($1));
}
gsub(/\./,"-");
if ($5=="Kunden ID") {next};
if ($6=="Summe") {next};
Buchungstext=($4 " " $5 " " $6);
Belegnummer=substr($4,1,7);
$15=$3;
gsub(/\,/,".");
disgeb = ($10+$11);
if ($3~/Rechnungskauf|Kreditkarte/ && $8~/0.19/) {$16="Erloes";$10="1220";$11=""}
else {$16="Erstattung";$10="";$11="1220"} 
#Steuersatz 
if ($8~/0.19/) $9="19";
else {disgeb=""; $12=$7};

print DDMMYY FS  Buchungstext FS Belegnummer FS $7 FS $9 FS $10 FS $11  FS disgeb FS $12 FS $15 FS $16 FS $20}
```

Comment: 1. Check out if you have in every .csv file empty string after `^Transaktionen`. Because `/^$/` mean "empty line". 2. Check out what carriage return used in csv files. If it's windows `\r\n`, try use `/^\r$/` instead of `/^$/`.

Comment: 1. I told you before (see my comments under [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42977022/1745001)) not to use range expressions. 2. What do you think `/./` or `NF > 0` do inside an action block? 3. As I'm sure you've been told many times, post concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can try to help you. 4. This time listen to the advice you get and ask questions if you don't understand it rather than ignoring it.

Comment: I might might be an autodidact but I started with awk some days ago and am no coder. I do not know how to get this problem solved. Mr. Morton tells me not to use range expressions... So what else? I did not invent them. I asked here how to print lines from line X that holds field X. In my case if $1 has "Transaktionen" skip this line and print all further lines but ommit them if $1 is empty. I asked and got told what you find in my code above. It works but not if I run the command over more than one input file :( So I looked for flagged conditions but the same ouput aka problem. So how ?